# Unwanted (or erratic) result of macro function

Tags: c, macros

The code below with the inputs 2, 3, 10 is intended to give the 12.5 as the result.([sum(2,3,10)(=15) + largest(2,3,10)(=10)] / smallest(2,3,10)(=2))
But it outputs 2.000 as the result, which is unwanted and wrong. Am I making a precedence error or what kind of a mistake am I making?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MIN( a, b ) ( ( a < b ) ? (a) : (b) ) // Why are the parantheses imporant?
#define MAX( a, b ) ( ( a < b ) ? (b) : (a) )
#define LARGEST( a, b, c ) ( MAX( a, b ) < c ) ? c : ( MAX( a, b ) )
#define SMALLEST( a, b, c ) ( a < MIN( b, c ) ) ? a : ( MIN( b, c ) )
#define SUM( a, b, c ) ( (a + b + c) )
#define EXPR( a, b, c ) ( (LARGEST( a, b, c ) + SUM( a, b, c ) ) /  SMALLEST( a, b, c ) ) 

int main(){
    float a, b, c;
    printf("Enter three integers!\n");
    scanf(" %f", &a);
    scanf(" %f", &b);
    scanf(" %f", &c);
    printf("The result is %f.\n", EXPR(a, b, c));   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I use the functions inside parentheses `#define EXPR( a, b, c ) ( ((LARGEST( a, b, c )) + (SUM( a, b, c )) ) /  (SMALLEST( a, b, c )) )`, it works perfectly. But why are the parentheses important?

Comment: Look at the preprocessor output (run `gcc -E yourfile.c | tail` or something) to see what the macros expand to.  Remember that macro expansion is just text substitution and nested macros are not evaluated in the sense function calls are.

Comment: Replace macros with functions and the code will ( magically )work.

Comment: This is definitely a problem of precedence between operators `+` and `?:` !!

Comment: Add parens with `SMALLEST( a, b, c )` --> `(( a < MIN( b, c ) ) ? a : ( MIN( b, c ) ))`. Same for `LARGEST()`.

Comment: In MIN and MAX do `((a) < (b))`. In other words, inside a macro, generally put parens around arguments when you use them. Similarly in the other macros.

Comment: To expand on what 2501 is saying:  Don't use macro's like this just for fun or to be clever.  There are legitimate uses for function-like macros in C.  They let you imitate some features of more advanced languages in situations where those languages are not practical.   And in RARE cases, can improve performance if you know what you're doing.  But they are a giant pain to debug and often make code less maintainable.  Try to solve your problems with JUST C FIRST and only use macros if you know exactly what short-coming of the language you are trying to overcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

to see the actual code generated by the preprocessor merely execute this command

```
gcc -E main.c
```

we will get (just the last part of the output from the last command )

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a, b, c;
    printf("Enter three integers!\n");
    scanf(" %f", &a);
    scanf(" %f", &b);
    scanf(" %f", &c);
    printf("The result is %f.\n", ( (( ( ( a < b ) ? (b) : (a) ) < c ) ? c : ( ( ( a < b ) ? (b) : (a) ) ) + ( (a + b + c) ) ) / ( a < ( ( b < c ) ? (b) : (c) ) ) ? a : ( ( ( b < c ) ? (b) : (c) ) ) ));
    return 0;
}
```

This is a little bit complicated

```
 ( (( ( ( a < b ) ? (b) : (a) ) < c ) ? c : ( ( ( a < b ) ? (b) : (a) ) ) + ( (a + b + c) ) ) / ( a < ( ( b < c ) ? (b) : (c) ) ) ? a : ( ( ( b < c ) ? (b) : (c) ) ) )
```

My first guess was as I stated in the comment was precedence

so let's take the left operand in `/` operator and ignore the rest for a moment to see the problem

```
(( ( ( a < b ) ? (b) : (a) ) < c ) ? c : ( ( ( a < b ) ? (b) : (a) ) ) + ( (a + b + c) ) )
                                        |-----------------------------------------------|
                                            the sum of the three operator will be added to the statement of the false condition ONLY (which is if a  or b is the largest in this case) first and then we will evaluate the ?: because as you know the + is higher than ?: in table precedence
```

so let's call the left block just treated (just above) **LeftBlock** to make things simple for the next analysis

So combined with the right operand of `/` operator  (or what is left from the whole statement ) we will get

```
LeftBlock / ( a < ( ( b < c ) ? (b) : (c) ) ) ? a : ( ( ( b < c ) ? (b) : (c) ) )
```

now the `/` is higher than the `?:` operator in precedence so this expression will be first evaluated

```
LeftBlock / ( a < ( ( b < c ) ? (b) : (c) ) ) ? a : ( ( ( b < c ) ? (b) : (c) ) )
|--------------------------------------------| 
          this is the condition for the ?: operator instead of only ( a < ( ( b < c ) ? (b) : (c) ) ) which is WRONG
```

As you can see the lack of parentheses leads to undesired result !!

There are many others pitfalls about macros that you should avoid you can check some of them from this [link](http://web.mit.edu/rhel-doc/3/rhel-cpp-en-3/macro-pitfalls.html)!

Finally I think I deobfuscated the problem !! :)

Answer (score 4):

Because macro expansions substitute each ocurrence of the macro textualy, for example consider this simple macro

```
#define SQR(x) x * x
```

this macro when used like this

```
double x = SQR(1.0 + 2.0);
```

will expand to

```
double x = 1.0 + 2.0 * 1.0 + 2.0;
```

which yeilds `5.0`, if you add the parentheses, they will be inserted too

```
#define SQR(x) (x) * (x)
```

and then it would expand to

```
double x = (1.0 + 2.0) * (1.0 + 2.0);
```

which yields `9.0`.